# Bandwidth throttling software

Tags: windows, bandwidth, latency

I need to be able to simulate high bandwidth/high latency/high packet loss on my pc for the purpose of testing the software that I'm writing.

I've seen some software that you can install on a separate machine that will act as a throttling router/gateway but 1) I didn't really trust the companies that I found 2) A separate machine isn't available atm.

I was talking to the network admin and he told me that he has heard of software that will throttle my own NIC (he didn't mention packet loss/latency though). Is anyone aware of any software that can do this?

I am asking this on SO as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was asked ([kinda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection/)) on SO before. The question was asking for a Firefox plugin, which we later found that [Firefox Throttle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5917) could simulate slow internet speeds. Several other options were given also - the author of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection/) specifically desired a plugin, which is why the plugin was accepted as opposed to an alternative.

Comment: +1 - from the link, Charles looks like what I'm looking for I'm going to check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using linux you can use [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle), which will do what you want.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation. I am, however, using windows. Updated the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it personally but I remember a sale guy telling me that VMWare Workstation could do this so you can simulate slow performance and multi OS etc when testing.

Answer (score 0):

A cellular card should do this quite well ;)