# How to downgrade a 120 Mbit line, to test website speed?

Tags: website, performance, connections, page-speed

**How to downgrade a 120mbit line** (our current connection) temporary to a 10mbit to test what our potential clients with less speedy internet are experiencing as the website loads?

At this moment everything loads in less than a second: For us there is now No Way to **EXPERIENCE** the built up of the pages visually as a user. Ive searched the plugin directory of FireFox over and over but nothing I could find there. Any and all tips are welcome!

## UPDATE

yeah would be nice though to just have some firefox plugin, you know,, where you can set the maximum virtual kbit, that way you can even experience how a person with 56K would experience. NOT that anyperson in the world would use that now, but just to dive into nostalgia for a minute and feel the internet experience of ten years ago (or a far far away user from other side of the world visiting your server... very handy to limit the speed to, say **1 Mbit**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bandwidth throttling software](http://serverfault.com/questions/50548/bandwidth-throttling-software)

Comment: set the server NIC to 10MBps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Tom's comment, if you set your pc/switch port to 10mbit, then it's very easy to replicate this

Comment: That's still relatively fast, and affects throughput more than latency, which may be a more serious real-world issue.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to throttle de bandwith just on your PC or at a Gateway level ?
Models and versions?

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a very good tool which has presets for bandwith throttling AND delaying of requests to simulate high latency networks.

To enable this go to *Rules / Performances / Simulate Modem Speed*, note that you can set the delay/throttling yourself using the *Rules / Customize Rules*.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I know about is [Comcast](https://github.com/tylertreat/Comcast). 
With it, you can limit your **bandwidth** as well as your **latency** and **packet-loss**.

As the owner of the project say "Simulating shitty network connections so you can build better systems."

Comment: At first I thought it was a joke but it's actually serious and looks nice.

Comment: @AndréDaniel and it works very well